# Get td class text using VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, class, selenium-chromedriver

So I want to take the text of td class.

The html page:

```
<table class="track-summary-details__info col-table ng-scope" ng-repeat="checkpoint in checkpointGroupCtrl.group.checkpoints">
        <tbody><tr class="track-summary-details__row ng-isolate-scope" ewf-checkpoint="checkpoint">
    <td class="track-summary-details__counter ng-binding" ng-bind="checkpointCtrl.item.counter">9</td>
    <td class="track-summary-details__status ng-binding" ng-bind="checkpointCtrl.item.description">Delivered</td>
    <td class="track-summary-details__location ng-binding" ng-bind="checkpointCtrl.item.location">EAST - UK</td>
    <td class="track-summary-details__time ng-binding" ng-bind="checkpointCtrl.item.time">10:46am</td>
    <td class="track-summary-details__pieces ng-isolate-scope" ewf-pieces="checkpointCtrl.item.pieces">
    <!-- ngIf: piecesCtrl.pieces.pieceIds.length --><div ng-if="piecesCtrl.pieces.pieceIds.length" class="ng-scope">
        <a data-tracking="{'type':'piecesItem','title':{'en': 'Toggle the pieces'}}" ng-click="piecesCtrl.togglePieces()" aqa-id="trackingResultsPieces">
            <i ng-class="piecesCtrl.arrowClass" class="dhlicon-carat-down"></i>
            <span ng-bind="piecesCtrl.pieces.amount" class="ng-binding">1</span>
            <span ng-bind="piecesCtrl.pieces.label" class="ng-binding">Piece</span>
        </a>
        <!-- ngIf: piecesCtrl.isPiecesVisible -->
    </div><!-- end ngIf: piecesCtrl.pieces.pieceIds.length -->
</td>
</tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

The text I want to take is "Delivered".

I tried using the xpath by copying it but the format is very strange :

/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMl9A.jpg)/div/div[2]/div[2]/table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMl9A.jpg)/tbody/tr/td[2]

So, I have tried this xpath :

```
Set elem = Selenium.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='track-summary-details__status ng-binding']")
```

Seems to be found because no error but the result is not good :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMl9A.jpg)

Do you have any idea to get the value ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be `elem.Text`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to have tested it without success but now, It works. Well done !

Comment: Result = elem.Text